# Как из inputa при нажатии на кнопку вывести информацию в Div?

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как из инпутов (розовая стрелочка) при нажатии на кнопку (синяя стрелочка) вывести текст на место желтой стрелочки. (java script)
Напишите примерно какая фунцкия нужна.

Comment: Нужна функция присвоения, и базовые знания JS.

Comment: мне бы понять как это написать))

Comment: вы это поймете как только прочитаете основы JS =) Сложно что то сделать не имея представления как это делать =)

Comment: А можете написать как это выглядит и я буду вам очень благодарен)

Comment: Конечно могу, мне не жалко, открываете гугл, набираете там "самоучитель javascript", и начинаете читать результаты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.addEventListener('click',function)` - чтобы обработать событие клика.

`input.value` - чтобы установить/воспринять значение `<input>`

`element.textContent` - чтобы установить текст в элемент или `element.innerHTML`, но если вы не вставляете элементы HTML разметки на страницу, лучше всегда использовать первый вариант.

Comment: Спасибо большое, оказывается Контент с маленькой написал, дурная голова))

Comment: @Dima, получили бы ответ еще почти час назад если бы ознакомились с правилами сайта, а именно - привели бы свой(пусть нерабочий) код в вопросе =)

Comment: Урок на будущее)